# How do I get the frames of cells in a UICollectionView before the screen has been presented?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

What’s the best way to get the positions of the first 3 cells in a UICollectionViewController’s collection view before pushing it onto the navigation stack?

For example:

```
let collectionViewController = SomeCollectionViewControllerSubclass(data: someData)
// @ TODO: get the frames of the first three cells here so I can create a fancy transition
self.navigationController.pushViewController(collectionViewController, animated: true)
```

Here's what I've attempted:

```
let collectionViewController = SomeCollectionViewControllerSubclass(data: someData)

// force load the view
let view = collectionViewController.view

// try to get a cell directly (result: nil)
println(collectionViewController.collectionView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

// try to ask the layout for the cell attributes (result: CGRectZero)
println(collectionViewController.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)))

self.navigationController.pushViewController(collectionViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to calculate it on your own if you can.

You can't access the cell views before they are on screen, because they will be created when the system need to display them to avoid creating them if it's not necessary.

So, you have to rely on your cell layout knowledge to know if you can evaluate their position (does your cells always have the same height for instance).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've been doing in the interim. I was hoping there was a more flexible solution, but this may have to do. Thanks!